# Setting Horizontal AxisOptions for datatype Date on a Line Chart

Tags: java, gwt, charts, google-visualization

I'm using gwt-visualization-1.1.2 in Java (not javascript) and I have my Line Chart all setup and working.

However, I am unable to tell the chart to use a custom x-axis using `haxis.ticks` or set a max value for the end of the x-axis using `hAxis.maxValue` as per the [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format). Since I cannot tighten up the x-axis right most date value, the scale goes out from 2010 to 2060. All I want to display is from 2016-2017 for my few data points.

Here is what I have attempted in order to get it working:

**haxis.ticks**

```
AxisOptions hAxisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
hAxisOptions.set("ticks", "1453349417000,1482293418");

AxisOptions hAxisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
hAxisOptions.set("ticks", "Date(2016,1,1),Date(2016,12,1)");
```

**haxis.maxValue**

```
AxisOptions hAxisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
hAxisOptions.setMaxValue("Date(2016,1,1)");

AxisOptions hAxisOptions = AxisOptions.create();
hAxisOptions.setMaxValue("1482293418");
```

I think this is tricky because this line chart is using a continuous scale (ie. dates). I have no idea how to create an array of ticks using gwt because the documentation is completely lacking any explanation of the sort (even the javadocs), so there's no point of reference.

If you know how I might be able to tighten up an x-axis scale/interval/step that is based on the Date type, that would be much appreciated.